# Error editing a question

Tags: bug

I would like to edit my question [How does the AGPL apply to services used in the backend?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/14331), but I get the error:

```
An error occurred submitting the edit.
```

As it does not indicate anything like the question being closed, I think it is a bug that should be reported. I do not get any further output and the browser console doesn't log any problem either.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem seems to be resolved.